# Correct order output in K Means and document clustering

Tags: algorithm, nlp, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am doing a single document clustering with K Means, I am now working on preparing the data to be clustered and represent N sentences in their vector representations.

However, if I understand correctly, KMeans algorithm is set to create k clusters based on the euclidean distance to k center points. Regardless of the sentences order.

My problem is that I want to keep the order of the sentences and consider them in the clustering task.

Let say `S = {1...n}` a set of n vectors representing sentences, `S_1 = sentence 1 , S_2 = sentence 2 .. etc`.

I want that the clusters will be `K_1 = S[1..i], K_2 = S[i..j] etc..`

I thought maybe transform this into 1D and sum the index of each sentence to the transformed value. But not sure if it will help. And maybe there's a smarter way.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do some kind of document segmentation and not clustering.  Maybe this strand of research would be relevant: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W08-1803

Comment: It's not k-means, or clustering anymore. You want so split your document into k segments, thats where the similarity ends IMHO. (P.S. there is a straightforward solution if you consider this a plain old optimization problem)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to do this would be to append each lexical item with the sentence number it's in. First [sentence segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation), then, for this document:

> This document's really great. It's got all kinds of words in it. All the words are here.

You would get something like:

```
{"0_this": 1, "0_document": 1, "0_be": 1, "0_really": 1,...}
```

Whatever k-means you're using, this should be readily accepted.

I'd warn against doing this at all in general, though. You're introducing a lot of data sparsity, and your results will be more harmed by [the curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality). You should only do it if the genre you're looking at is (1) very predictable in lexical choice and (2) very predictable in structure. I can't think of a good linguistic reason that sentences should align precisely across texts.